# EntityNotFoundException for aws glue "get-partition"

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax, aws-cli, aws-glue

I'm trying to get metadata about Glue partitions via the CLI. I've tried following [the docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/get-partition.html) but I keep getting the following error:
`An error occurred (EntityNotFoundException) when calling the GetPartition operation: Cannot find partition.`

I know that my CLI is set up right because I can get partitions when I run`aws glue get-partitions --database-name my_db --table-name my_table --max-items 10`.

Here are the commands that I've tried. What am I doing wrong with the syntax?

- `aws glue get-partition --database-name my_db --table-name my_table --partition-values "year" "2022", "month" "04", "day" "29", "hour" "16"`
- `aws glue get-partition --database-name my_db --table-name my_table --partition-values "year" 2022, "month" 04, "day" 29, "hour" 16`
- `aws glue get-partition --database-name my_db --table-name my_table --partition-values year 2022, month 04, day 29, hour 16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close.  `--partition-values` is just looking for the values (not names and values)

Try the following

```
aws glue get-partition --database-name my_db --table-name my_table --partition-values "2022" "04" "29" "16"
```